# Property of non-object in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel 4 and I'm getting this error when I attempt to create a menu with a dropdown

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php) (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php)

I can't see where I'm going wrong

My master.blade.php

```
 <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">work<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            @foreach($dropdowns as $dropdown)
                <li>
                    {{ $dropdown->title }}
                </li>   
            @endforeach
        </ul>
</li>
```

My PageController

```
$currentPage = new Page($pages[0]->id);
$dropdowns = $currentPage->getPagesSelectList("parent", "", "");
return View::make('index', compact('dropdowns'));
```

My Page model

```
public function getPagesSelectList($name, $default = "", $js = "", $flag = true)
{
    $list = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'default' => $default,
                'js' => $js,
                'pages' => $this->getSubPages($flag, $default)
            );

    return (object)$list;
}

public function getSubPages($flag, $default, $parent = 0, $num = 1)
{
    $pages = array();
    $pageSql = \Page::where('parent', '=', $parent)->orderBy('num', 'ASC')->get();
    foreach ($pageSql as $result) 
    {   
        $page = new Page($result->id);
        $page->setFromDatabase();
        $page->default = $default;
        $page->select = '';
        if( $page->id == $default )
            $page->select = $default;
        $page->space = $num;
        if(!empty($page))
            $pages[] = $page;
        $children = $page->getSubPages($flag, $default, $page->id, $num + 1);
        if(!empty($children))
            $pages[] = $children;
    }
    return array_flatten($pages);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the other code works fine, in Blade instead of:

```
@foreach($dropdowns as $dropdown)
<li>
    {{ $dropdown->title }}
</li>
@endforeach
```

you should use:

```
@foreach($dropdowns->pages as $dropdown)
<li>
    {{ $dropdown->title }}
</li>
@endforeach
```

This is because in `getPagesSelectList` you assign result of `getSubPages` to `pages` index of array and then you convert array to object.